# SQL queries to pull data from IBM i (AS400) - How to separate multiple queries

Tags: ssrs-2008, ibm-midrange, db2-400

What is the query separator used in AS400 to run multiple statements in same SQL . We have GO statement in MS SQL similarly I though semicolon is used in AS400 to separate multiple queries but for some reason it’s not working.

> I actually have multiple steps in this query
>
> 1. Crete a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
> 2. Insert the data in to this Global temp table
> 3. Some logic to update the data on this Global temp table by
>      joining with other table.
> 4. Select the value from this Global temp table

When I use semicolon to separate each step I get error saying semicolon is not recognized as query separator… Below is the snippet of the query

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.FinalRes
(
       SLSTRTY  CHAR(4)
       ,SLSMAN CHAR(5)
       ,CSTNAM CHAR(30)
       ,CustN  CHAR(16)
       ,ADR1 CHAR(30)       
       ,ADR4 CHAR(30)
       ,"STATE" CHAR(2)
       ,ZIPCD CHAR(12)
       ,DTEADDED DATE
       ,SalesCM DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,SalesYTD DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,SalesPY DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,EXTGPCM DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,EXTGPYTD DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,EXTGPPY DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,GMYTD DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,GMCM DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,GMPY DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,SalesPYM DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,SalesPYTD DECIMAL(22,7)
       ,STATIND CHAR(1)
       ,CSTCLS CHAR(3)
       ,CSort NUMERIC(5)
) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;

SELET * from SESSION.FinalRes
```

***This is the error I get when I try to execute the query***

> SQL0104: Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: END-OF-STATEMENT.
>   Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ;.  Token ;
>   is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is
>   .  This list assumes that the statement is correct
>   up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the
>   syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery
>   . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again:
>   -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token ;. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it
>   could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of
>   clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL
>   statement because it does not end with a valid clause.

Comment: did you really meant to include the TAG sql-server? this isn't sql-server syntax

Comment: How are you trying to execute this SQL?  IBM i Navigator?  STRSQL?  RUNSQLSTM?

Comment: How many time are you going to post the same question?

Comment: I am trying to run this query from SSRS. I have setup OLE DB with Provider=IBMDA400 (this provider is part of IBM i Navigator for windows) in Microsoft SSRS tool. Query is working fine if i have only one statement in it i,e my connection is setup correctly. Only when i try to run multiple statement in same query which is separated by semicolon i am getting this error.

Comment: Did you try the GO syntax since you are running from SSRS?

Comment: Yes i tried GO but i got below error when i replaced semicolon with the GO statement  ---'Error :  SQL0199: Keyword GO not expected. Valid tokens: IN ON NOT UNIT WITH RCDFMT.
Cause . . . . . :   The keyword GO was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword GO.  The partial list of valid tokens is IN ON NOT UNIT WITH RCDFMT. This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   '

Comment: I tried experimenting with this and it looks like the query from within SSRS is only expecting a single statement.  Maybe you can create a stored procedure or is there any way to structure your query without the temporary table?

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 for i SQL will prepare and execute [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE] only one dynamic statement per invocation.  Although I have not had the opportunity to use the feature, since the DB2 for IBM i 7.1, there is apparently support for a **Dynamic Compound Statement** to be accepted.  The statement separator [for both declarative and procedural statements] in a compound statement, is the semicolon.
http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg011514-story02.html
**Dynamic Compound Statements In DB2 For i**
Published: January 15, 2014
by Michael Sansoterra

Answer (score 1):

Probably this has already been accounted for, but your 'select' keyword is missing a 'c'. Also try putting an additional semicolon after the select statement.